# Insert into with multiple selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which I want to insert data, and the values itself have to come from multiple tables. This has to be done as follows, by reading the MySQL documentation:

```
insert into flight(airlinecompanyId,planetypeId)
select id from airlinecompany where naam = 'Brussels Airlines',
select id from planeType where type = 'Boeing 737';
```

So simply explained, I want to insert the id's from the tables airlinecompany and planetype that I demand via the where clausule, into the flight table column.

When I try this query, I keep getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' select id from planeType where type = 'Boeing 737'' at line 2
```

Someone who has a solution?

Comment: How are these two tables (`airlinecomapny, planetype`) related? You are inserting two columns -- do the two tables have an exactly identical number of ids?

Comment: They don't have a relationship but airlineCompanyId and planetypeId are both foreign keys in the flight table, if that's what you mean?

Comment: What is your goal then? If `planeType` and `airlinecompany` are not related themselves, are you trying to insert a single row for those two values?

Comment: http://oi60.tinypic.com/nx46t4.jpg

This basically is the ERD. I just want to have a seperate table with a planetype together with a airlinecompany...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having no relationship between `airlinecompany` and `planeType`, you needn't necessarily perform a `JOIN` to do the insert, but since you are creating only a single row in `flight`, it can easily be done with subselects, wrapping each table's `SELECT` statement  in  `()`

```
INSERT INTO flight (airlinecompanyId, planetypeId)
  SELECT
    (SELECT id FROM airlinecompany WHERE naam = 'Brussels Airlines'),
    (SELECT id FROM planeType WHERE type = 'Boeing 737')
  /* MySQL will permit this with no FROM clause */
```

It can alternatively be done with a `CROSS JOIN`, since there's only one possible row returned:

```
INSERT INTO flight (airlinecompanyId, planetypeId)
  SELECT
    ac.id,
    pt.id
  FROM
    airlinecompany ac
    CROSS JOIN planeType pt
  WHERE
    ac.naam = 'Brussels Airlines'
    AND pt.type = 'Boeing 737'
```

Comment: Ok, the above one was the most easy one and did the job!
Thank you!